# JComponent fails to initialize with: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width and height must be >= 0

Tags: java, swing, awt, install4j, jcomponent

I have an installer created with install4j that fails to show anything at all, other than the background image, on a screen that contains a Installation Directory Chooser component that as far as I can tell from the stack trace is based on a Swing JComponent.

The problem only occurs on a specific Windows Server 2016 server and no other environment I've ever tested it against. There are other components on the same screen but through trial and error I found out that everything shows up fine once I disable/don't build the above JComponent/Directory Chooser.

Here's the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width and height must be >= 0
    at java.awt.Component.getBaseline(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getBaseline(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.calculateBaseline(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.beans.screens.components.ScrollablePanel.getPreferredScrollableViewportSize(ScrollablePanel.java:13)
    at javax.swing.ViewportLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.BorderLayout.preferredLayoutSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.preferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.GetLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.getLayoutInfo(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.ArrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.arrangeGrid(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.GridBagLayout.layoutContainer(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.CardLayout.show(Unknown Source)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.activateScreen(WizardBase.java:138)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardScreen.activate(WizardScreen.java:43)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.ScreenEnvelope.activate(ScreenEnvelope.java:166)
    at com.install4j.runtime.wizard.WizardBase.setScreen(WizardBase.java:122)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.WizardScreenExecutor.execute(WizardScreenExecutor.java:293)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.controller.Controller$1.run(Controller.java:155)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: i think , in your code you must be putting some image or text , or any other stuff that needs rendering in a UI component but that method/function that you're using to do that needs to calculate the size of that component to rendering into it to do the rendering correctly , but it cant because the size is not specified , or the size is dynamic and currently it has zero dimensions because nothing is inside.

Comment: I think you're on the right path @TheGoldy but I don't understand why it would happen for only certain Operating systems (windows 2016) and nowhere else.

Comment: height is somehow greater then 0 on that OS tell me if you find out why

Comment: The user that was having this issue ended up running the executable with a different user and it all worked well. Both users were admin users so I would have to dig around more to find the user permissions specifics and how they affected this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being related somehow to windows user permissions/settings.

The installer/executable user that was having this issue ended up running the executable with a different windows administrator user and it all worked well.

Both users were admin users so I would have to dig around more to find the differences in user permissions and how they affected this issue.